# bash won't enter to else

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have this code that expects string from the end user:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "You are about to deploy the site from STAGING to PRODUCTION, Are you sure? yes/no ";

read continue

if (( "$continue" == "yes" )) ; then
        echo "Yes"
else
        echo "No"
fi
```

The problem is that the else will never be.

Thanks

Comment: Use `[[` not `((`, see https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-parenthesis-explained

Answer (score 0):

Use test (`[...]`), not double-parens:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "You are about to deploy the site from STAGING to PRODUCTION, Are you sure? yes/no ";

read continue

if [ "$continue" == "yes" ] ; then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```